# Flutter Firebase my Android apiKey is different in Firebase Google json file and Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-computing, firebase

The latest file I downloaded through FlutterFire from Firebase. When I try to generate the Google Play Integrity token using the default ID, it doesn't work. However, when I change the ID to the Google Cloud ID, the Play Integrity token works, but other services stop functioning.

but ios working fine because allover id is same in google cloud and Firebase.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7pj6.png)